# Volley throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-volley, gson

I am working on Gson using volley package but it throwing error. my url is ok. it giving me json value on browser but in method it throws null pointer exception. from stringRequest line it goes directly on try block and return null value like this "0x239c9b75 NORMAL null"

please help me to solve this issue.

```java
 public void getJobs() {
      //  mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //for open jobs Client/GetOpenJobs
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, RestAPI.getInstance().urlString+ "Getrewardlist?businessid="+1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        getRewardList = (new Gson()).fromJson(response, GetRewardList.class);
                        try {


                            if (ResponseCode == 200) {

                                RewardListEntity[] Items = getRewardList.entitiesList;
                                if(Items!=null&& Items.length>0) {
                                    Utilities.R_entities = Arrays.asList(Items);
                                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    return;
                                }else{
                                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No jobs exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            } else  {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                           String ResponseMessage = e.getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ResponseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyError e = parseNetworkError(error);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return;
                    }

                    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        if (volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
                            VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
                            volleyError = error;
                        }

                        return volleyError;

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
              //  params.put("SessionToken", RestAPI.getInstance().sessionToken);
                return params;
            }
        };
        try {
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, 60, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            VolleyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: it is not really clear where is the NPE could you specify the line and probably some kind of a stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out the response first thing

```
Log.d("",response);
```

See if it is actually received in the callback, if it does - the issue might be the way you parse the response with Gson.

Hope this Helps!